# Looking for a site with custom instructions

Tags: instructions, set-database, moc

I'm looking for a website that has some cool custom model instructions. I have a LEGO store near me and I'm able to buy pieces individually. I'm looking for more of a sci-fi ship kind of instructions.

Comment: https://dinorobo.com seems to have been deleted, I guess I'll remove the link.

Comment: @mindstormsboi I checked the dinorobo page in the Wayback Machine, and it appeared to have been a scrape of a Flickr page that's still available (and now added to the Wayback Machine as well): https://www.flickr.com/photos/21545821@N03/with/6432497709/

Answer (score 10):

There are quite a few individual sites out there offering that sort of thing, however one of the best I've come across is:

> [The MOC pages on Rebrickable.com](http://rebrickable.com/mocs)

This is because the site allows you to catalogue all your parts and then search for other sets and MOCs you can build with your existing collection.

Answer (score 5):

[The Unique Brick LEGO Creations](http://www.theuniquebrick.com/) provides pdf instruction files, for a fee; but they don't seem to carry sci-fi creations.

Answer (score 0):

This **website** has custom instructions, categorized by age and type.
[**www.buildingexamples.com**](http://www.buildingexamples.com/)
A nice feature is that they also provide Apps for smartphones and tables.
Have fun!