# Looking for instructions to build a hobbit hole without 'custom set pieces'

Tags: instructions

I've searched on ['rebrickable'](http://rebrickable.com/search?q=hobbit&theme=0&numpieces=0&maxpieces=5050&year=1950&yearto=2016&custom=1&pt=0&c=-1&sets=&showprints=1) for anything hobbit related, but I can't find it.

This is what I'm thinking of:

[image: An unexpected journey]

> 79003-1: An Unexpected Gathering

I'd rather buy a large bucket of 'free for all' lego bricks, that can be made into the Hobbit hole, but I've [not found any instructions](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1224/7056).

Are there any instructions for a similar structure?

Comment: You can use the [LEGO digital designer](http://ldd.lego.com/en-us/) to try and build an alternative. It's piece sets are limited, so probably what you've got access to. Once done, it can generate a printable instruction booklet. May be a bit more work than you desire, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have an alternate plan you might consider:

- Reference: [here's the entry for that set on Brickset](http://brickset.com/sets/79003-1)
- It looks like there aren't many custom pieces used in this set, as seen in the parts list
- You could download the actual instructions for the real set, and then just swap out some pieces, removing the color combinations that you don't have

I hope this helps in some small way!